# Mac OSX Retain Release Strong etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I come from iOS world, now with ARC and "strong".

I'm targeting OSX 10.6 and greater, does Mac use ARC & garbage collection? Can someone point me to a guide on these matters regarding 10.6 or above?

Comment: FWIW, ARC is *not* garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

ARC and strong are available in OS X 10.7 and 10.6.  If you use 10.6 you can't use ARC's zeroing weak references (they don't zero).

GC targets the same sort of problem ARC does, but comes at it from a different direction.   You can use it starting in 10.5.   GC will work even when you have retain cycles.   However GC has somewhat unpredictable results on runtime (you don't know exactly when your problem will get paused for a garbage collect cycle).

If you use ARC on iOS and are happy with avoiding retain cycles there, and don't need zeroing weak references, it'll be simpler to do that on OSX then to learn the nuances of GC.   If your use of ARC depends on zeroing weak references (for example to break retain cycles), either don't support 10.6, or adopt GC.

Apple's release notes at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_7.html have some details.

Answer (score -1):

Starting Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard there is Garbage Collection available in Mac OS X.

ARC is a compiler feature. Runtime still manages memory by retains/release, but all this is hidden from developer.

Comment: So I can turn on ARC, and then just follow the ARC guidelines that I have been using for iOS 5?